# Select paper source in php printing solution

Tags: php, printing, postscript, tray

Hi I've got a PHP printing solutions using sockets.
Using this function/class.

```
public function printJob($queue){

        //Private static function prints waiting jobs on the queue.
        $this->printWaiting($queue);

        //Open a new connection to send the control file and data.
        $stream = stream_socket_client("tcp://".$this->host.":".$this->port, $this->errNo, $this->errStr, $this->timeout);
        if(!$stream){
            return $this->errNo." (".$this->errStr.")";
        } else {

            $job = self::getJobId();//Get a new id for this job

            //Set printer to receive file
            fwrite($stream, chr(2).$queue."\n");
            $this->debug .= "Confirmation of receive cmd:".ord(fread($stream, 1))."\n";

            //Send Control file.
            (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) ? $server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : $server = "me";//Might be CLI and not have _SERVER
            $ctrl = "H".$server."\nPphp\nfdfA".$job.$server."\n";
            fwrite($stream, chr(2).strlen($ctrl)." cfA".$job.$server."\n");
            $this->debug .= "Confirmation of sending of control file cmd:".ord(fread($stream, 1))."\n";

            fwrite($stream, $ctrl.chr(0)); //Write null to indicate end of stream
            $this->debug .= "Confirmation of sending of control file itself:".ord(fread($stream, 1))."\n";






            if (is_readable($this->data)){

                //It's a filename, rather than just some ascii text that needs printing.  Open and stream.
                if (strstr(strtolower($_ENV["OS"]), "windows")){
                    $this->debug .= "Operating system is Windows\n";
                    $data = fopen($this->data, "rb");//Force binary in Windows.
                } else {
                    $this->debug .= "Operating system is not Windows\n";
                    $data = fopen($this->data, "r");
                }

                fwrite($stream, chr(3).filesize($this->data)." dfA".$job.$server."\n");
                $this->debug .= "Confirmation of sending receive data cmd:".ord(fread($stream, 1))."\n";

                while(!feof($data)){
                    fwrite($stream, fread($data, 8192));                     
                }
                fwrite($stream, chr(0));//Write null to indicate end of stream
                $this->debug .= "Confirmation of sending data:".ord(fread($stream, 1))."\n"; 

                fclose($data);

            } else {                      

                //Send data string
                fwrite($stream, chr(3).strlen($this->data)." dfA".$job.$server."\n");           
                $this->debug .= "Confirmation of sending receive data cmd:".ord(fread($stream, 1))."\n";

                fwrite($stream, $this->data.chr(0)); //Write null to indicate end of stream
                $this->debug .= "Confirmation of sending data:".ord(fread($stream, 1))."\n"; 

            }
        }

    }
```

All is well with it but I can't seem to control the paper source/tray that the printer then selects.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Or perhaps a different solution that I an use, I like this one because I can send the ip address (no need for install), postscript file and it prints out.
So if there is another solution that requires the same things then I can use that.

I'm using PHP, iis, windows.
Richard

Comment: Just done some reading and this seems interesting.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280522/pdf-print-from-c-program-with-ghostscript-on-specific-tray notable the PSDocOptions  and the PSPageOptions  functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is more a question about the printing system on the OS you are using (you don't seem to say what that is). I also can't see where the print job is taking place, is this C# code ?

All printer have properties, included in which are things like the tray setup. When printing you need to configure the device, the steps for doing that are going to be different per OS. For example, on Windows 8+ you would need to set up a job ticket. I don't recall exactly how its done on earlier versions of Windows, some complicated structure as I recall. On Linux it would depend if you are using CUPS, if you are you would probably need to set up a CUPS pipeline for the specific tray you wanted to use.

I see there is some code testing to see whether the OS is Windows or something else. I guess you will need to figure out wht to do in there.

[added later]

OK so now I understand better what you are doing. Since you are using Ghostscript to create PostScript from your PDF file the question does make more sense.

The link you noted above and the PSDocOptions and PSPageOptions is what you need, combined with luser_droog's points about tray selection.

So first you need to find out what your printer expects in the way of PostScript in order to change trays. Your PPD file contains ths:

```
*InputSlot Internal/Cassette 1 (Internal): "<</ManualFeed false>> setpagedevice statusdict begin 0 setpapertray end"
*InputSlot PF60A/Cassette 2: "<</ManualFeed false>> setpagedevice statusdict begin 1 setpapertray end"
*InputSlot PF60B/Cassette 3: "<</ManualFeed false>> setpagedevice statusdict begin 4 setpapertray end"
*InputSlot PF60C/Cassette 4: "<</ManualFeed false>> setpagedevice statusdict begin 5 setpapertray end"
*InputSlot EF1/Envelope Feeder: "<</ManualFeed false>> setpagedevice statusdict begin 2 setpapertray end"
```

So to select 'cassette' 1 the required PostScript is:

```
<</ManualFeed false>> setpagedevice statusdict begin 0 setpapertray end
```

Now assuming you are using a **recent** version of Ghostscript (ie at least version 9.16) you can then add, as part of your PDF to PostScript command line;

```
-dPSDocOptions="<</ManualFeed false>> setpagedevice statusdict begin 0 setpapertray end"
```

Which will set the current tray to tray 1 before starting the job. Note that your PostScript file is no longer device-independent, it will now only work reliably on that class of printer.

If you wanted (for example) page 1 to be printed on cassette 1 and page 2 on cassette 2 you would need to use PSPageOptions, eg:

```
    -dPSpageOptions=["<</ManualFeed false>> setpagedevice statusdict begin 0 setpapertray end"
 "<</ManualFeed false>> setpagedevice statusdict begin 1 setpapertray end"]
```

I'm assuming that you are deploying this in a particular organisation, rather than open to the world. However it might be good to stick a note somewhere that Ghostscript is AGPL licenced, and if this was ever made available as a general service, the entire source code would probably have to be made available (the AGPL covers software as a service).

Comment: Hi this is a snippet of PHP code. It's IIS so that's windows. 
The current setup is generate PDF in php (mpdf). Use ghostscript (command line) to create PS script send to printer using IP address. The printer doesn't then have to be installed on the server. This is for a business with alot of printers so making it simple. 

I think I've got a solution in that link (bugs.ghostscript above) I need to get my hands on a printer for testing (should have been step 1 sorry) and I'll post back with the results/answer.

Comment: Wow magic. you know your ghostscript. Just as a followup and to fully polish off the answer. My question is what would it be if I had x pages and I wanted them all to be on Tray 2. Would I need multiple `<</ManualFeed false>> setpagedevice statusdict begin 1 setpapertray end` one for each page?

Comment: No, if its a document-wide setting you can use -dPSDocOptions. PSPageOptions works one per page (so entry 1 in the array is attached to page 1, entry 2 to page 2, etc). When it reaches the end of the array, it wraps round. So if you want settings applied to odd and even pages you only need to supply the odd, and then even, options. That would then apply entry 1 to page 1, entry 2 to page 2, entry 1 to page 3 etc. By the way, the syntax in the answer may not be correct, that's working from memory which is notably unreliable for me. Its documented in ps2ps2.htm in the gs/doc directory.

Comment: cheers for that I'll have to do some time sting at the end of the day. But you got me on the right path and given me the right variables to look at. For that I'll accept this answer. When I've got it working I'll add in the bars I've used but its a printer specific thing at the end the day so you can't know that from memory! Thanks for all your help

Comment: I've finally gotten round to this, I try and do "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.15\bin\gswin32.exe" -dPSDocOptions="<</ManualFeed false>> setpagedevice statusdict begin 0 setpapertray end" -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile="..." inputfile.pdf - in various different ways (-sPSDocOptions) remove the space etc - nothing - I get the error -dName= must be followed by a valid token. Ideas?

Comment: It could be a bug :-) It'll have to be a -s anyway I think, not a -d as that won't accept arbitrary strings IIRC.

Comment: Yeah does seem that way,  do you know where the string needs to go in the P's file. So I could just str replace or something

Comment: Per document, at the head should be OK, per page, needs to go somewhere specific, I forget where. Your best bet will be to open a bug report.

Comment: Right, added a bug report awaiting reply. In the end just added in the 
<</ManualFeed false>> setpagedevice statusdict begin 1 setpapertray end
Snippet after the 1st %% BeginPageSetup 
Job done.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to require printer-specific postscript code. You should search for .PPD files (postscript printer definition) for the specific printers you need to use.

The .ppd files are ascii text in a special format, but easily human-readable. Any special capabilities of the printer that cannot be done in standard postscript (but still achievable with postscript) are documented this way.

I've done a similar style of printing in the past, by using the unix `telnet` command specifying the ip-address and port, and redirecting the input to be my ps file. The same should be possible with the windows shell using a command-line telnet program.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply - just trying to wrap my head around what you are saying. I've got my postscript file - check. I've got my ppd file - link.
https://www.openprinting.org/download/PPD/Kyocera/en/Kyocera_Mita_FS-1920_en.ppd
Are you saying that I've got to then put the specification from the ppd file into my ps file. I'm using ghostscript (commandline) can I use this to help me?
Cheers for your help.

Comment: Further reading here, 
http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=690182
Might be the answer.........
Time will tell